# UITextView restrict to edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextview

I have textview to user can write some text and after click the submit button i want to restrict the user edit the previous/old text. But they can add more text. how can i do this?

```
tips_bgText = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(610,390,318,231)];

 [self.view addSubview: tips_bgText];

 -(void)submit:(id)sender{

 }
```

Comment: in submit just set tips_bgText.enabled = NO;

Comment: Later i need to add more content but won't edit previous text

Comment: In submit action, write this statement `txtView.editable = FALSE;`.

Comment: @SweetAngel: No. I don't want to stop USERInteraction but i want to edit the previous text what entered

Comment: You can compare previous text or text length  when user edit the text in respective `UITextView` delegate method. If it returns TRUE, then display this text in textview and allow user to add more text. And one more thing is when text submitted successfully, you have to set `txtView.editable = TRUE;`,(for example: when view loaded next time) otherwise you cant add or edit text.

Comment: @user3743552 try having two text views v1 and v2(for e.g.)make v1 non editable and v2 editable.Copy contents entered in v2 to v1 and clear it from v2 on submit button click.This way you can achieve what you want

Comment: @user3743552 Please try to see my answer. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this one. And please make some change according to you.

```
    .h file
    Declare this variable


    int lastTextCount;

    .m file

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        lastTextCount = [tips_bgText.text length];
    }

-(void)submit:(id)sender
{
    lastTextCount = [tips_bgText.text length];
}


    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
    {
        int length = textView.text.length + (text.length - range.length);

        if (length >= lastTextCount)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
            return NO;
    }

i Hope it helps you
```

Comment: @user3743552 What kind of problm your are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
@interface ViewController (){
NSString *savedString;
NSString *editString;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
savedString  =   @"Hi Hello";
editString  =   @"";

}

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range    replacementText:(NSString *)text{
if([text isEqualToString:@""]){
    if(savedString.length != editString.length){
        editString     =   [editString substringToIndex:[editString length] - 1];
        return TRUE;
    }
}else{
    if(editString.length == 0){
        textView.text   =   [savedString stringByAppendingString:text];
    }else
        textView.text   =   [editString stringByAppendingString:text];

    editString      =   textView.text;
    return FALSE;
}
return FALSE;

}
```

savedString is the string you save after you click 'submit'. 
Hope this helps.